Probability in a non equiprobable sample space

At a certain pizzeria, there are five different toppings available and
a pizza can be ordered with any (possibly empty) subset of them on it.
In how many ways can one order an unordered pair of pizzas such that
at most one topping appears on both pizzas and at least one topping
appears on neither? (CMIMC Combinatorics/4)

I want to calculate the probability of a randomly ordered pair of unordered pizzas meeting the restriction in the question.
Wrong approach: The unordered pairs that meet the restriction is $271$. And the number of unordered pairs is $528$. However, because the unordered pairs is not an equiprobable sample space, the probability isn't:
$$\frac{271}{528}$$
Right approach: Number the pizzas. The number of ordered pairs is $2^5\times 2^5=2^{10}=1024$, of which valid ordered pairs is $325$ (again from the linked solution). Hence, the probability is:
$$\frac{325}{1024}$$
Hence, even though the question asks for unordered pairs, if we want to calculate the probability, we need to switch to ordered pairs, and do the calculations.
Is this logic correct?
